# Swift Firebase query returns null when filtering uid

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I tried to retrieve all the entries that belong to a user by comparing their uid with the uid attribute of the entry.

```
 ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
 self.ref?.child("Entry").queryOrdered(byChild: "uid").queryEqual(toValue: uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [weak self] (snapshot) -> Void in
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
        print(snapshot)
```

Which returns

```
Snap (Entry) <null>
```

Currently I have this data structure:

- Entry

  - KgZkrnjFYXG9zKzfgh5

    - date: "Mar 31, 2017"
    - text: "test 123"
    - uid: "vKSJm500zCQmy2TTFUgv8FepknF2"
    - wordcount: "6"
- Users

  - vKSJm500zCQmy2TTFUgv8FepknF2

    - Email: "test7@test.com"
    - Provider: "email"

Following these rules :

```
"Users": {
  "$uid": {
    ".write": "!data.exists() || auth.uid === $uid",
    ".read": "auth !== null" 
  }
},

"Entry":{
    ".read" : "auth != null",
    ".write" : "auth != null",
    ".indexOn" : "uid" 
}
```

Im a little confused because when I try to print out the query by itself, I get

```
 let query = self.ref?.child("Entry").queryOrdered(byChild: "uid").queryEqual(toValue: uid)
    print("/n")
    print(query)

Optional((/Entry {
ep = "Optional(\"vKSJm500zCQmy2TTFUgv8FepknF2\")";
i = uid;
sp = "Optional(\"vKSJm500zCQmy2TTFUgv8FepknF2\")";
}))
```

I'm not sure what that means. Should I change the query to go through the autoIDs before I order it by uid?

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't the firebase query, it was how I stored the UID. 
When I query'd through my database, I was using

```
    Optional(\"vKSJm500zCQmy2TTFUgv8FepknF2\")
```

instead of

```
    vKSJm500zCQmy2TTFUgv8FepknF2
```

A quick change on the optional value fixed it.